# Display ALL Categories(everything!) ONLY in the sidebar (Left menu bar / navigation) in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, sidebar

Hello there I would like to display only the Root Category and any of its First Level Categories in the top menu bar (Main menu / Navigation) whereas in the sidebar (Left Menu bar / navigation) - I'd like to display all categories with all the subcategories (First Level, Second Level,...).

How can i achieve this? I've tried many workarounds but they don't seem to work at all / make a difference at all.

To sum up...

**Main menu**

```
Cat 1    | Cat 2    | Cat 3
Subcat 1 | Subcat 2 | Subcat 3
```

**Sidebar / Left Menu**

```
Cat 1
Subcat 1
Sub-Subcat 1
Subcat 2
Sub-Subcat 2

Cat 2
Subcat 2
Sub-Subcat 2
Subcat 3
...
...
ALL CATEGORIES
```

Answer (score 1):

For your sidebar you could use any of the following extensions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-sidebar-navigation-5952.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-4554.html

For the top Navigation menu, you need to go to your Admin Panel.
In `Configuration`, on the left in `Catalog`, in the `Category Top Navigation` section set `Maximal Depth` to 2.

Answer (score -2):

Open **magento\app\design\frontend\default\testTheme2\layout\catelog.xml** and paste the code below.